# Ubuntu 18.04 - cryptsetup fails to recognize passphrase, unlocking from Live USB works

Tags: 18.04, encryption, luks, xps, cryptsetup

I recently bought a Ubuntu Edition Dell XPS 13 9370. The machine comes without full disk encryption enabled out of the box, but offers to create a recovery USB drive, when booted from that Ubuntu can be installed with LUKS encryption.

However, after installing my passphrase is never recognized, I always get "cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?"

- The culprit can't be keyboard layouts, the passphrase `abcd` does not work either.
- The encryption itself seems to be configured correctly - when I boot from the live USB system and launch the "Disks" utility I can successfully unlock the drive with my chosen password (again, I tried `abcd`, so it can't be a layout problem)

Did anybody else see this problem? Any suggestions how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

---

Here are some suggestions.

- Switch to the command-line by hitting <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, type the password again, and check for any errors. If you find the error, try searching for it.
- When you wait few minutes, you should be shown `initramfs`/*BusyBox* console screen. Using the command-line, you should check the syntax of your kernel arguments by typing the following command:

  ```
  cat /proc/cmdline
  ```

  Especially check (as suggested by *BusyBox*):

  - The value of `root`, whether it points to the right device.
  - If `rootdelay` is set, maybe you need to increase the system wait?

---

If above won't help, consider the following commands:

- `cryptsetup --debug luksOpen /dev/XXX mapper-name` to decrypt manually (see this [how-to](http://www.jootamam.net/howto-basic-cryptsetup.htm)).

  <sup>Note: To make sure you're using the right device, run `dumpe2fs /dev/XXX` (e.g. `sda1` or `nvme0n1p3`) in `initramfs`/*BusyBox* console, then make sure it reports as `crypto_LUKS`.</sup>

  <sup>Note: If `luksOpen` fails, try the older syntax: `cryptsetup --debug luksOpen /dev/XXX ubuntu`.</sup>
- `cryptsetup --debug luksDump /dev/XXX` to dump LUKS header information from the device.

  <sup>Note: In case of corruption of on-disk metadata, use `cryptsetup repair <device>` command.</sup>
- On *Please unlock disk XXX_crypt* screen, note your device name and using above `luksDump` method, confirm that Ubuntu asks you to decrypt the right device as the order (disk number) potentially can change (BIOS boot changes?). In that case, Ubuntu likely will use the last known device (cached, `/etc/lvm/[backup|archive]/`?) location when it won't be able to connect to [`lvmetad` service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/166832/21471).

  For example, I was asked to type a passphrase for `nvme1n1p3_crypt` (Windows NTFS partition) instead of `nvme0n1p3` (`crypto_LUKS` partition).

Further suggested commands:

- Run `lvm lvs` or `lvm vgscan` and check for any errors (it identifies each disk with a UUID).

  <sup>See also: [Ubuntu won't boot because of lvmetad](https://askubuntu.com/q/745218/78223) & [Failed to connect to lvmetad - Stuck on boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/969917/78223).</sup>
- `cat /proc/modules` to check for missing modules (load it by `modprobe`).

When finish, type `reboot` to restart.

---

If you did an upgrade recently, test your previous kernel (hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot, and select *Advanced options*), and select the version which you'd like to test.

---

Other related resources:

- [How can one unlock a fully encrypted Ubuntu 11.10 system over SSH at boot?](https://askubuntu.com/q/66785/78223)
- [Ephemeral error message: "cryptsetup: unknown fstype, bad password or options?"](https://askubuntu.com/q/717428/78223)
- `lvm2` bug in Ubuntu 18.04: [lvm2-activation-generator crashed with SIGSEGV](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/1767747).

  Similar older bug: [error unlocking / decrypting LUKS volume at boot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1481536).
- [UEFI Introduction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) & [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/78223)